# .net core console app on linux - the application to execute does not exist

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have console based micro service that runs on RHEL7 distro during scheduled time. The binary is published as self contained - single file and trimmed flags, it is working very well for last 2 weeks, but today the application could not start because of below error

The application to execute does not exist 'logs/slk/.net/AppName/5kp4eef5.q5/AppName.dll'

When i looked the directory path already existed, when i removed the path and started the app again, it worked. It looks like .net is trying to extra sing file binary but failed to do so and throws this error. I have plenty of free space so not sure why extraction failed.

is there a better way to know why extraction failed and clean up after upon failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this is a known issue in .net core  https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/3778